# django-report-builder [3.1.12] - Not displaying field for subset of models

Tags: python, django

I am trying to setup django-reportbuilder for a new website, but I am facing an issue as the report are not displaying any fields for a subset of my models (ie : when I click on them, the field list stay empty and I can see the line : [02/Aug/2015 13:36:15]"POST /report_builder/api/fields/ HTTP/1.1" 500 113566 in the server log). 
For example, for the model below, I am never getting any fields back in the GUI :

```
class Mission(models.Model):

MISSION_STATUS_CHOICE =  (
    ('NEW', u'Nouvelle mission'),
    ('ASSIGNED', u'Assignée'),
    ('VALIDATED', u'Validée'),
    ('ARCHIVED', u'Archivée'),
    ('CANCELLED', u'Annulée'),
    ('PENDING_CH', u'En attente de validation après un changement'),
    ('DRAFT', u"En attente avant publication"),
)
RATE_CHOICE = (zip(range(1,6), range(1,6)))

pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Publication',auto_now_add=True,)
mission_begin_date = models.DateTimeField('Date de debut de la mission')
mission_end_date = models.DateTimeField('Date de fin de la mission')
mission_reservation = models.ForeignKey('Reservation',null=True,blank=True)
appartement = models.ForeignKey('Appartement',null=True,blank=True)

assigned_ae =  models.ForeignKey('authentification.Agent',null=True,blank=True)
mission_competences_requises = models.ManyToManyField('authentification.Competence',blank=True)
task_nettoyage = models.BooleanField('Nettoyage')


mission_rate = models.IntegerField(choices=RATE_CHOICE,null=True,default=None,blank=True)
mission_paid = models.DecimalField("Rémunération mission", default=0,max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)    
status = models.CharField(max_length=15, default="NEW",choices=MISSION_STATUS_CHOICE)
facture
```

I am not sure if it could be because it has ManyToMany relationship as all my models with the same issues) ? I am using Django==1.8.2

Thank you,

EDIT ==

I found the solution, some of the verbose_name of my model were containing unicode characters but were not unicode string. It was strangely not causing issues anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that the djangorestframework 3.2.0 is not compatible with the last version of the django report builder. Try djangorestframework 3.1.3

have fun !

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, altough I am using djangorestframework 3.1.3 already! Should I try a lower version ?